# angular.js multiple js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, gruntjs

I have a growing angular app, and my index.html already looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/spin.js/spin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/overlay.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/jquery-shake.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/libs/bower/pwstrength-bootstrap/dist/pwstrength-bootstrap-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/controllers/import.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/controllers/login.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/controllers/main_page.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/controllers/manage_users.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/controllers/new_user.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/auth.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/services/httpAuthInterceptor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/services/spinnerHttpInterceptor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/utils.js"></script>
```

I dont want my index.html to be a mess and Require.JS is not an option cause it must be used with angularAMD which is incompatible with angular route resolve - a mandatory part of my app.

How can i clean up my JS load? I heard about Grunt, How can it help me? It's only a task runner...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "angularAMD which is incompatible with angular route resolve"?  In what scenario is route resolve does not work for you when using angularAMD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is not to minify angular js part, it's not best practice. 
Try this grunt plugin, it's angular builder, and it takes care of your dependecies and another stuffs, just read the description.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-builder

Also you can use html2js to load your templates into $templateCache, so your app will not go to the server every time you need another template.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-html2js

If you try to user RequireJs or Browserify JS, it can help in some cases, but it does not take care about your dependecies, and project structure. also you will have a troubles with writing unit tests if your app use requireJS and Browserify. So my suggestion is not to use these two modules with Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Grunt can help a lot, via its plugins.  In particular, look at the plugin [usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin), which lets you put in comments around your html to identify how you want to package your files.  Then when you run the associated grunt task, it will pull the `<script>` tags out of your html, concat and minify the files associated with them, and replace them with a single `<script>` tag pointing to the concatenated & minified result.  Pretty slick.

Comment: Yes and CSS too; so you end up with 1 html file, 1 css and 1 js, all minified.